# pine script 4: Variable 'buySignal' was declared with 'series[integer]' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[bool]'

Tags: pine-script

How can I convert below two lines to version 4 of pine script:

```
isBuyPlotted=nz(buySetup)==9?false:buySignal[1]==true or isBuyPlotted[1]==true?true:nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY+1])==9?true:false // init
buySignal:=nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY])>9-MAXSIGNALDELAY and close>nz(high[1]) and nz(close[1])>nz(open[1]) and nz(close)>nz(open) and not isBuyPlotted
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the context isn't in your code snippet, but this should work:

```
isBuyPlotted = false
isBuyPlotted := nz(buySetup)==9?false:buySignal[1]==true or isBuyPlotted[1]==true?true:nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY+1])==9?true:false // init
buySignal = false
buySignal := nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY])>9-MAXSIGNALDELAY and close>nz(high[1]) and nz(close[1])>nz(open[1]) and nz(close)>nz(open) and not isBuyPlotted
```

Comment: thank you! ... I completely over analyzed it. Instead of assigning true or false I was assigning 1 or 0 values. duh!